# How to plot histogram of total population by state

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I have a .csv file with the columns "total population" , "state", "county",.... (other columns)

I'm looking to plot a histogram with the x axis showing the states and the Y axis showing the population. How would I go about this?

Comment: Read [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html). There are a lot of examples there.

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner myself I find it difficult to use .csv or .txt so I just decided to write the data in the code. Now, if you wish to display X-axis for country and Y-axis for population, this is a way to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

countries = ['Cambodia', 'Thailand']
populations = [16245729, 69183173]

x = countries
y = populations

plt.xlabel('Country')
plt.ylabel('Population (in tens of millions)')
plt.title('Populations 2018')

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```